# Reason for Voltage drop in Depletion Region in a PN Junction

Tags: potential, semiconductor-physics, diffusion

So I've been reading about the PN Junction and depletion region quite a lot, but I haven't really found a concrete explanation for the existence of a Voltage Drop, or Barrier Potential associated with the depletion region after the formation of the electric field due to diffusion of majority charge carriers from both sides to the other.

**Can someone explain the reason for this barrier voltage, which ultimately in equilibrium ceases diffusion, as in, makes the rate of diffusion equal to the drift current...**

**I would also like to know about the shrinking and expanding of the Depletion Region with regards to the biasing of the Diode.**

Comment: Nope, it asks a completely different question if you read the context in the post.

I want to know why the voltage drop exists? Is it due to some sort of energy band related thing of the p,n  and depletion region? Or is it because of the electric field? If it is because of the electric field? How and why does the voltage drop occur due to it?

Answer (score 0):

The spatial variation of potential is known as [band bending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_bending). It happens whenever there is a non-uniform dopant concentration, and also at the junctions of dissimilar materials. In a pn junction, the n-type semiconductor has a much higher concentration of electrons than the p-type semiconductor, so in the absence of any electric field, there will be a diffusion of electrons from the n side to the p side, resulting in an electron diffusion current toward the n side. Likewise, holes diffuse from the p side to the n side, resulting in a hole diffusion current toward the p side.

The only way equilibrium can be established (meaning zero current) is if there is an electric field in the junction pointing toward the p side. This field gives rise to a drift current toward the p side, balancing the diffusion current. Since E-field is the negative gradient of potential (pointing from high potential to low potential), this requires a higher potential on the n side. In other words, a potential barrier is formed that counteracts the free diffusion of carriers toward the lower-concentration side.

As for how bias affects the depletion width, this is best asked as a separate question, but a brief qualitative explanation can be given as follows. A forward-biased junction no longer has zero current, so less drift current is needed to balance the large diffusion current toward the n side. This means that a smaller and narrower potential barrier is required, i.e. the depletion region is narrower. The opposite is true for a reverse-biased junction.

Comment: The diffusion current is a result of both, the hole diffusion current and the electron diffusion current right? So why does the Electric field need to be pointed towards the p side to balance the Diffusion current? Also why does the drift current rise towards the p side? isn't the conduction band of the p region higher than the conduction band of the n region?If anything, the electrons and holes should be drifting from p side to n side

Comment: Both diffusion current components point toward the n side (remember that electrons are negatively charged), so the drift current must point toward the p side. Yes, the conduction band edge of the p side is higher, but remember that $E_C = -q\phi + \text{const.}$ where $\phi$ is the potential. This means the p side has lower potential. I don't know why you think this means electrons and holes should both be drifting from the p side to n.